# Getting order by given order android SQlite Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have an book mark option in my application, here to sort in SQLITE by "order by" using selected  set of column values (ID) like: order by (ID=1,5,4,3) so I would get record 1, 5, 4, 3 in that order out,

But it show id=1,2,3,4,5 in listview please any one help me.

databasehelper activity

```
public Cursor getBookMarks() {
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db =myDataBase;// getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb1 = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String [] sqlSelect1 = {"0 _id", KEY_NAME,KEY_PH_NO,KEY_ID}; 

        String sqlTables1 = TABLE_BOOKMARK;
        String strQuery1=KEY_PH_NO+"='1'";
        strOrder1=KEY_ID + "  DESC";
        qb1.setTables(sqlTables1);

        String strvalues="";

        Cursor curs = qb1.query(db, sqlSelect1, strQuery1, null,null, null, strOrder1);

        if(curs!=null)
        {
            curs.moveToFirst();
            if(curs.getCount()>=1)
            {
                do 
                {
                    strvalues+=""+curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))+",";
                }
                while (curs.moveToNext());

                if(strvalues.length()>=1)
                {
                    strvalues+="-1";
                    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "TB","Version","Book","Chapter","NKJ"};
                    String sqlTables = "hindibible";

                    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
                    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
                    String strOrderbook="Book" + " desc";

                    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
                    strQuery.append("ID IN (" +strvalues + ")"); 
                    StringBuilder strOrderBy = new StringBuilder();
                    strOrderBy.append(" CASE  ID ");
                    String [] arrIDs = strvalues.split(",");
                    for(int i=0;i<arrIDs.length;i++)
                    {
                        strOrderBy.append("  WHEN " + arrIDs[i] + "  THEN " + arrIDs[i]);
                    }

                    strOrderBy.append(" END");
                    Cursor bible = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, strQuery.toString(), null,null, null, strOrderBy.toString());

                    bible.moveToFirst();
                    return bible;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("setBookMark",e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly please!

Comment: i M new to this android field,please give your sugestion@Gosu

Comment: `ORDER BY`, sorts the output in ascending or descending order. It does not show the results in an ordered sequence given by you.

Comment: I mentoned when and then ex when id==1,4,6 then id =1,4,6 this way to display the datas, in my dtable i have 50 book titles it shows asc order if i select book 5,4,2   to add the book mark the result will be  2,4,5  but i want inthe order of 5,4,2 only @Prerak Sola

Comment: Cursor bible = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, strQuery.toString(), null,null, null, strOrderBy.toString());       here strorderby.tostring is order by clause  @Prerak Sola

Comment: i dont want to asc or desc order ,i just want to last selected item  display the top of the listview but it similar to desc order please give me the solution I spend lot of hr but i cannot solve this problem@PrerakSola

Comment: Add a column in your bookmark table with name `insert_id`. Set it to auto increment so whenever you insert a new bookmark it will increment. Than display the bookmarks in the listview in descending order using this id. You will get the latest added bookmarks at the top.

Comment: thank u so much @PrerakSola  i just modify my code it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying this

```
if(curs!=null)
{
    List<Cursor> listCursor = new ArrayList<Cursor>();      
    curs.moveToFirst();

    if(curs.getCount()>=1)
    {
        do 
        {
            String strID = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
            String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "TB", "Version", "Book", "Chapter", "NKJ"}; 
            String sqlTables = "hindibible";

            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            qb.setTables(sqlTables);

            StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
            strQuery.append("ID = "+strID); 

            Cursor bible = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, strQuery.toString(), null,null, null,null);
            listCursor.add(bible);
        }while (curs.moveToNext());

        return listCursor;
    }
```